# lxml.etree._ElementTree.find() can't be called on objectify.parse result

Tags: python, lxml

```
>>> from lxml import objectify
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> f = StringIO("<root>data</root>")
>>> tree = objectify.parse(f)
>>> type(tree)
<type 'lxml.etree._ElementTree'>
>>> tree.find('root')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1944, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.find (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:45105)
TypeError: find() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
>>> tree.find()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1926, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.find (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:44970)
TypeError: find() takes at least 1 positional argument (0 given)
>>> print tree.find.__doc__
find(self, path, namespaces=None)

        Finds the first toplevel element with given tag.  Same as
        ``tree.getroot().find(path)``.

        The optional ``namespaces`` argument accepts a
        prefix-to-namespace mapping that allows the usage of XPath
        prefixes in the path expression.
```

Note that `tree.getroot().find` works and `find` works on `_ElementTree` instances created by `etree.parse`.

Tha main question: how can the same method raise these two mutually exclusive exceptions? Also, while I can use `tree.getroot().find`, the shorter form would be preferred if it worked as documented, so I'm curious, is it a lxml bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solve this mystery by looking at the corresponding source (long live OSS):

```
def find(self, path, namespaces=None):
    u"""find(self, path, namespaces=None)

    Finds the first toplevel element with given tag.  Same as
    ``tree.getroot().find(path)``.

    The optional ``namespaces`` argument accepts a
    prefix-to-namespace mapping that allows the usage of XPath
    prefixes in the path expression.
    """
    self._assertHasRoot()
    root = self.getroot()
    if _isString(path):
        start = path[:1]
        if start == u"/":
            path = u"." + path
        elif start == b"/":
            path = b"." + path
    return root.find(path, namespaces)
```

`"lxml.etree.pyx", line 1926` is the first and `"lxml.etree.pyx", line 1944` the last line of the sniplet, so there are in fact two different `find` methods. Apparently objectify constructs some different objects (and thus this is a bug in lxml) that do not accept the `namespaces` parameter. If you use `lxml.etree.parse` to parse your `StringIO` object, the API works just fine.

Comment: I've seen the source but didn't get that exceptions mean different `find`'s, thanks.